# Easy object persistence in Vala (like shelve/pickle)

Tags: python, vala, gobject, object-persistence

I would like to transfer my code from Python to Vala, but i ran into problems.

Is there an easy method to store objects created in Vala, like you can do it with pickle/shelve? I would like to avoid running an entire database.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Technically this question is against the rules, because you are asking for a library here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I have given you an answer anyway, but my answer is more to the question of "How can i find Vala libraries / API methods?".

Comment: Also your question title should be phrased as a question, like "How can I persist GObject objects to a file?" or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know shelve/pickle, but have you tried to search for `persist` or `serialize` on [valadoc](http://www.valadoc.org)?

I did a quick search and found something in the json-glib library:

http://valadoc.org/#!api=json-glib-1.0/Json.gobject_serialize

http://valadoc.org/#!api=json-glib-1.0/Json.gobject_deserialize